# cakephp 2 custom exceptions are ignored

Tags: php, exception, selenium-webdriver, cakephp-2.1

I am using the excellent PHP-SeleniumClient class in one of my cake2 app's components (https://github.com/Nearsoft/PHP-SeleniumClient). When the class throws one of its own exceptions (e.g. element not found etc.) and I wanna catch that execption in a try/catch block, the catch statement is ignored.

Instead, the exception seems to be passed to cake's own error handling mechanism which renders the exception into the view. Any ideas to overcome this and assure that third party exceptions are not handled by cake's error handling?

I already found some instructions in cake's errorHandler.php comments. For example to create an own exception handler, use a custom renderer or use `AppController::appError();`. But from there I am still a bit lost.

Any ideas and solutions are greatly appreciated. Thx